# PassThrough nodelet with more than one field

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS users, I am using the passthrough nodelet ([link text](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros/Tutorials/PassThrough%20filtering)) on a point cloud. Setting one field parameter (like in the tutorial) works. What I want to do is to use the nodelet to filter all the fields (x, y, z) at the same time. Since the param "filter_field_name" is only one, how I can achieve that?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226940/passthrough-nodelet-with-more-than-one-field/) by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 620 on 2016-02-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arifzaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/69915/arifzaman/) on 2021-05-14**:
Respected member I am very much new to ROS and I exactly want to filter the xyz all at one so have you got any launch file for this? Kindly share it I will be very much thankful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although it doesn't seem to be currently documented on the wiki, the pcl_ros package also has a nodelet available for a crop box filter (feel free to add your own documentation!). You can see the description of the crop box filter [here](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/blob/jade-devel/pcl_ros/pcl_nodelets.xml#L174-L178), and the [dynamic reconfigure config file for the crop box filter](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/blob/jade-devel/pcl_ros/cfg/CropBox.cfg) should tell you what parameters to set and what they do.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2